# OpenId Connect accessing both graph api and on prem resource with single login

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs4.0

Trying to get a ASP.NET web application to access both a local resource and graph api using a single login.
The environment consists of a on prem adfs as well as a Azure AD instance that is synced and federated against on prem ad.
I have the following working.

1. Configure the application to use OpenId Connect authentication against Azure AD with a client configured in azure ad. The user authenticates and i receive a authentication code that i can use to get a token to call graph api successfully.
2. Configure the application to use OpenId Connect authentication against ADFS using a client_id configured in ADFS. The user authenticates and i get a authentication code that i use to get a bearer token to call the local resource.

However i cannot find a way to get access to both the local resource and graph api with a single login. Is this at all possible? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Delegated token which contains both a valid Client and User.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#permissions) and Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890014/accessing-microsoft-graph-api-without-using-login-page).

If it is just read-access and not write-access then what you are describing should be possible.